# Are APNS now guaranteed delivery given that passbook passes are guaranteed

Tags: ios

I was just flicking through some material about passbook and read that it has guaranteed delivery.
As its based on APNs, does that mean that apps using APNs unrelated to passbook now also get guaranteed delivery?
If not, why not, if it can be done for passbook APNs?

Comment: Good question, though it is not programming related.

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) still states `Remember that delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed.`

Comment: Not Apple documentation (I haven't gone through that yet) but see point 3 here  http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1 "Apple’s push notification service (this time delivery is guaranteed)". Doing a quick search, I found Apple documentation saying pass updates are not guaranteed, but didn't immediately see what it says about initial delivery. Personally I don't see how anything involving comms can ever be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming: "Apple’s push notification service (this time delivery is guaranteed)". This is vague and from a 3rd party that does not further elaborate. Passes that are time fenced appear based on the time, not due to a push notification.

Pass updates are indeed notifications, the pass appearing is not. Basically guaranteeing delivery is most likely impossible and at best would have so many caveats as to be not guaranteed.