# Only half of push notifications reach devices (APNS)

Tags: php, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

```
$usersStmt = self::$db->query("SELECT `token` FROM `tokens`");
$users = $usersStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

foreach ($users AS $userToken) {
    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $userToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $apnsMessage);
}
```

I have a table with 10 push notification tokens inside of it. Using PHP, I fetch these tokens and send a notification for each token to APNS.

The problem is, only half are actually getting the notifications. I have a feeling that this is because one of the tokens is invalid (or something along those lines) and it is stopping it from sending the rest of the tokens.

I have checked the value of `$result` and each one returns true. This means that all notifications are being successfully sent to APNS but not delivered to all devices.

Is it possible that an invalid token could disrupt the rest of the notifications from reaching devices? I'm not sure what's going on here but I know all the notifications are sent successfully to APNS but not reaching the devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid tokens will not disrupt the rest of the notifications from reaching devices.
I have the same issue before, the problem was with messages sent itself. 
Check your messages length, the notification payload is 256 bytes ).
Check your messages encoding, use the escape sequence for none ASCII messages.
If you send to same device multiple times, Apple will send the last notification only.
Make sure your tokens is for the same working environment, sandbox tokens will not work with production server.
Check Apple technical notes for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Apple [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html):

"Remember that delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed."

(Linked relevant question with the same answer - thanks to Joe)

[Are APNS now guaranteed delivery given that passbook passes are guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863560/are-apns-now-guaranteed-delivery-given-that-passbook-passes-are-guaranteed)

Answer (score 0):

The current adoption rate of iOS 7 to iOS 8 is 50/50. Have you made sure your apps register separately for each OS in your didFinishLaunching call in the AppDelegate? Does the data suggest it's working for one OS and not the other? example code in App Delegate:

```
if(iOS8){

    [self.application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [self.application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    NSLog(@"Register for iOS 8 Notifications %@", application);

}else{

    // iOS 7 Notifications
    [self.application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    NSLog(@"Register for iOS 7 Notifications %@", application);
}
```